# recommender systems: Convert UUIDs to 32 bit ints for recommender libraries

Tags: hash, hashtable, recommendation-engine

[LightFM](https://github.com/lyst/lightfm) and other libraries ask for a 32 bit integer id e.g for users. But, our user id is a UUID e.g. `0003374a-a35c-46ed-96d2-0ea32b753199`. I was wondering what you would recommend in scenarios like these. What I have come up with is:

- Create a bidirectional dictionary either in memory or in a database to keep a UUID <-> Int mapping. e.g. https://github.com/jab/bidict
- Use a non cryptographic hash function like MurmurHash3 or xxHash. For e.g. for 10 million UUIDs, I got around 11,521 or 0.1% collision using `xxhash`. Is that negligible for a recommender system?

I'm also curious on how this would apply in an online prediction scenario, where given the UUID, user interactions and the model, I have to predict the recommendations for a model which needs 32 bit integers. If I use the in memory bidict approach, then that won't work in this case and hence I may have to create a persistent key-value store in the worst case.

Comment: What's the purpose of using UUIDs? Perhaps a sequential guid is possible for the user id instead? Otherwise you're going to want to check for collisions, but it sounds like you're going to need to do that anyway...

Comment: @BurnsBA. It was a production decision for our analytics system across devices made before we started thinking of recommender systems. It won't be possible to change it now unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This will definitely work, and is probably the solution the vast majority of users will choose. The disadvantage lies, of course, in having to maintain the mapping.
2. A hashing function will also work. There are, in fact, approaches which use hashing to [reduce the](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.03993.pdf) [dimensionality](https://github.com/maciejkula/spotlight/tree/master/examples/bloom_embeddings) of the embedding layers required. One thing worth bearing in mind is that the resulting hash range should be relatively compact: most implementations will allocate parameters for all possible values, so a hashing function that can hash to very large values will require exorbitant amounts of memory. Hashing following by a modulo function could work well; the trade-off then is between memory required to hold all parameters and collision probability.

In LightFM as well as most other implementations, recommendations can only be made for users and items (or at least for user and item *features*) that were present during the training. The mapping will then be a part of the model itself, and be effectively frozen until a new model is trained.

Comment: The latest lightfm docs seem to indicate that user and item ids no longer need to be 32 bit integers. https://lyst.github.io/lightfm/docs/lightfm.data.html

It says: "To create a dataset: - Create an instance of the Dataset class. - Call fit (or fit_partial), supplying user/item ids and feature names

that you want to use in your model. This will create internal mappings that translate the ids and feature names to internal indices used by the LightFM model"

Does this mean that we can use string user/item ids, and they will be translated into internal int ids?